# Calendar: symbols-function-definition is void: "appt-make-list"

Tags: init-file, calendar, diary

When in the "calendar", typing "d", which runs (diary-view-entries), gives me an error *Symbols-function-definition is void: "appt-make-list"*.

It shows the (one) entry for this date correctly, though.

The allegedly "void" function is well present in appt.el.gz, from where I could do "Ctrl-x Ctrl-e".

Pressing "d" again, I get the same error. Calling (appt-make-list) explicitly gives me another error.

My guess is that from my latest working version to my current version (25.2.2) there have been lot of more changes than I can trace down but need some advice on how to do this right with the current version.

On the net, there is a lot information about "appt-make-list", but most of it outdated.

**Question is:** what have I do so I can see my diary entries from calendar without errors?

---

This is what is in my .emacs about calendar:

```
(require 'appt)
(setq calendar-mark-diary-entries-flag t)
(calendar);;;(mark-diary-entries)(kill-buffer "diary")
```

where the first two lines are edited and activated by Ctrl-x Crtl-e without restarting emacs.

---

Lines that include "Diary" are:

```
    749:(add-hook 'diary-hook 'fancy-diary-display)
    750:(add-hook 'diary-hook 'appt-make-list)
   1331:(setq calendar-mark-diary-entries-flag t)
   1332:(calendar);;;(mark-diary-entries)(kill-buffer "diary")
```

Comment: There seems to be a missing `(require 'appt)` somewhere. You can add it to your init file and restart emacs: that should eliminate the error.

Comment: @NickD does not help: (require 'appt) followed by Ctrl-x Ctrl-e and then again "d" from calendar gives error: "Symbols ... fancy-diary-display". I really think that my about 3 decades old .emacs file needs rework on how to use calendar; looks like there are too many changes to start fixing them one by one.

Comment: Yes, there is no such thing any longer: there is `diary-fancy-display` but that's part of `diary-lib.el` which should be loaded. A good cleaning of your init file is indeed probably in order!

Comment: @NickD : "A good cleaning of your init file is indeed probably in order! " that's exactly what I think of it. How to do it? My init-file has way too much valuable stuff to discard of all of it. So what is needed for calendar to work nowadays?

Comment: At a minimum, fix 749: `(add-hook 'diary-hook 'diary-fancy-display)` and move them all closer together, since they are related.

Comment: @NickD changing things to "(add-hook 'diary-hook 'diary-fancy-display)
;;;(add-hook 'diary-hook 'appt-make-list)" worked (in a new instance), thanks a lot!